# How to skip payment step in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm using prestashop 1.7.6.8. In my process the client can take the item from the store or get it delivered and the payment will be when receiving the item.

Is there any way to remove payment method step or redirect it to the next step in tpl file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the payment option "cash on delivery" to allow the customer to pay after receiving the order.

It's a native Prestashop payment module. You can install it as any other payment method.

If it's not what you are looking for, you can also override the OrderController class to add or remove a step, but in my opinion, the "payment method" way is much simpler.

Comment: When I tried removing ```addStep``` in OrderController the checkout process is stacked after selecting delivery method and I can notice the the step is removed.  (I commented this lines 388-397: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/577be593d195410a3a610d54c7f5d6b443b19d6f/controllers/front/OrderController.php#L388)

any idea on how to force checkout end after delivery selection?